# Access sub category in JSON python

Tags: python, json, get

What is the code required to print the `ContractName` sub category (under `result`) ?

I know to get result I have my dictionary `result` :

```
response_dict = response.json()
print()response_dict["result"]
```

But how do I get `ContractName`??

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "message":"OK",
   "result":[
      {
         "SourceCode":"test",
         "ContractName":"DAO",
         "CompilerVersion":"v0.3.1-2016-04-12-3ad5e82",
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this question does not display the minimum amount of Python knowledge required to ask a good question. `response_dict["result"]` is a list. Do you know how to access items in lists? What data type does the one element in the list have? Do you know how to access values in this data type? If you can't answer these questions please go through any Python tutorial.

Comment: In additional to the valid comment from @timgeb I wonder why *result* is a list. In your sample data it only contains one element but the mere fact that it's a list implies that it's been designed to accommodate more than one item. How would you want to proceed if it contains multiple elements?

Comment: @timgeb response_dict is a dictionary `<class 'dict'>` is the result I get when running type(response_dict). I know how to access the item in the dictionary, but I don't know how to access an item within an item in the dictionary

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Why can't you do `result_list = response_dict['result']; result_dict = result_list[0]; result = result_dict['ContractName']` or simply `result = response_dict['result'][0]['ContractName']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of *result* in your dictionary is a list. That list, in your example, contains one element which is another dictionary.

Therefore:

```
response_dict['result'][0]['ContractName']
```

...will give you what you need.